# Incorrect URL paths

Tags: uri

I am using Drupal on [this website](http://www.ciob.org.uk/).

On [this page](http://www.ciob.org.uk/membership/routes/epa) you will see that the URL is pointing to a page under another sub page as opposed to the [programmes page](http://www.ciob.org.uk/programmes).

When I changed the URL alias of one of the pages under the incorrect path it did not like it and now redirects to the page called Membership/routes which is part of the incorrect URL

`http://www.ciob.org.uk/membership/routes/epa-resources-2012`

How can I change this to actualy be this url, which would make far more sense?

`http://www.ciob.org.uk/membership/programmes/epa-resources-2012`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that by having a page actually aliased with `programmes` everything that you alias with `programmes/something` is resolving to plain `programmes`. That's maybe why the `programmes/epa-resources-2012` that you are trying to use "won't stick".

I would suggest that you try moving `programmes` to -> `programmes/index` or something like that. That way nothing will be "owning" the programmes path, and you will be able to have `programmes/anything...` paths.

Comment: I will look again at the alias set up on programs you may be right, If I can change that back to /membership/programmes then I could start adding pages under that url, I will try this and get back

Comment: I am taking this as answer as the url was being specfied ciob.org.uk/programmes and it should have been /membership/programmes. This is what prompted the change.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing I can think of that would cause Drupal out of the box to redirect "programmes/something" to "programmes," assuming both are node paths. A bad path should return a 404 error. If "programmes" is the path for a view, it would take "something" as an argument, and finding no results it would use the default value for the argument, but that does not appear to be the case here.

What are your alias and redirection settings? For example, if you have Drupal set to keep and redirect old aliases, you'll have to delete the unwanted bad paths under URL Aliases or correct them under URL Redirects, depending on what you have installed. If you have it set to keep old aliases but do not have Path_Redirect installed, the old alias gets treated as canonical. Any newly created aliases will bring up the correct node, but the location in the browser bar will be the older one.

I would also investigate whether any global redirection is set on /membership*.

Comment: There is no global redirection from membership, I will investigate using your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understand the issue, but if I do: are you using path_redirect? This has an option to automatically create a redirect when a node's URL alias is altered. It can be very useful, but it can trip you up in this situation (and also lead to an over-populated URL-space if your clients like to rename pages a lot:). To find out, you can go to the redirects config screen and search for programme.